# Windows Identity from Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm making the example in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.100).aspx, and it works for a Console Application very well. But I want something like it for my project in Silverlight 5, but I can't to adapt it. It tells me: `WindowsIdentity is not found here`. Can somebody help me? I just need know the UserName used for the user to login to windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight works in a more restricted manner than standard windows desktop application, such as console application you tried. Not only `WindowsIdentity` but also some other ways to get current user's UserName using .NET framework are not available in Silverlight, for example :

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
Environment.UserName
```

Some alternatives suggested as answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176566/get-current-windows-user-name-within-silverlight) (see answers those aren't accepted), mostly by creating web service to get UserName, and Silverlight application simply call web service's method. [This concise but complete blog post](http://blog.davemdavis.net/2011/04/11/getting-a-users-windows-identity-in-wcf/) shows you how to create such web service (WCF).

Comment: thaks so much @har07, for my present purposes, Environment.UserName Works very well, regards from México