# How to Get Window Username in Silverlight page

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

How to get window Username in silverlight page.

I try with below link but its give blank.

http://rouslan.com/2009/03/12/20-steps-to-get-together-windows-authentication-silverlight-and-wcf-service/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/keithmg/archive/2010/12/11/silverlight-get-user-or-windows-credentials.aspx

[Get current Windows user name within Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176566/get-current-windows-user-name-within-silverlight)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47520/Silverlight-Windows-User-Identity-Name

Any help will be highly Appreciated

Thanks in Advance,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Add below code in Page_Load() of default.aspx page

```
String WindowsUserName;
System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User;
User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
WindowsUserName = User.Identity.Name;
Char[] Spliter = { '\\' };
String[] user = new string[2];
user = WindowsUserName.Split(Spliter);
//WindowsUserName = user[1]; //" + WindowsUserName;
InitParams += ",WindowsUserName=" + WindowsUserName;//",WindowsUserName=ram";
```

Step 2 : Add below code in Application_Startup() of App.xaml page in silverlight application

```
string msWindowsUserName = e.InitParams["WindowsUserName"];
```

Comment: But doesn't this solution presume the IIS installation is on an internal network?  Our clients are in external firms, so System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User will be our IIS' anonymous user, or Network_Service, etc.  Something local to the server, not the user.